# Ubuntu server 20.04 can't connect througth ssh and not giving video

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh, video

I have an ubuntu server for testing, and yesterday the power goes down for an hour when the power comes back the pc started working but I couldn't connect to the server with ssh, I tested to connect an HDMI cable, and is not giving video. I can't see the video but it seems that the hardware is working fine.

Comment: There is no video output during boot at all? No manufacturer logo? No access to BIOS?

Comment: nope nothing through HDMI I looking for VGA to check there.

Comment: Seems like you have disproven "*the hardware is working fine*." Were it working fine, you would get video output during boot (before the OS loads).

Comment: As other people have suggested this sounds like a power management issue..

This is the official URL U think you should start with 'Fix Suspend and Hibenate' on that webpage.
 

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement